# how to continue setinterval function after clearing it

Tags: javascript

Hello evreyone I want to know how to continue setsetinterval function after clearing it starting from the last value
for example I created counter and i cleared it at the value "10" how to make it start counting again starting from the last value "10"
this is my code

```
let
div = document.getElementById("test");
button = document.getElementById("btn");
let time =_ =>

    this.time = 0
    counter = setInterval(function()
                {
                    this.time = this.time+1;
                    div.innerHTML=this.time + "s"
                }
                ,1000);
    

time()
button.onclick = function()
{
    clearInterval(counter)
}`
```

Comment: You can't. You've to set a new interval. To make that easier, don't pass an anonymous function expression to `setInterval`. Instead, declare the function (or assign it to a variable), and pass a reference to that function to `setInterval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

.js

```
let time = 0;
let counter = null;

let div = document.getElementById("test");
let button = document.getElementById("btn");
const startCounting = () => {
  counter = setInterval(() => {
    time += 1;
    div.innerHTML = time + "s";
  }, 100);
};

const startOrStop = () => {
  if (counter) {
    clearInterval(counter);
    counter = null;
  } else {
    startCounting();
  }
};

button.onclick = function () {
  startOrStop();
};
```

.html

```
    <div id="test"></div>
    <button id="btn">Start/Stop</button>
```

Here is the sandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-thunder-q4vmc?file=/index.html:115-182

Comment: words can't describe how how grateful i am thank you <3

Comment: I am glad, that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

This code is weird but you can just again do it:

```
counter = setInterval(function()
                {
                    this.time = this.time+1;
                    div.innerHTML=this.time + "s"
                }
                ,1000);
```

And interval should work again and I would name this function:

```
counter = setInterval(nameOfFunction, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a variable to control whether `setInterval` is going:

```js
var intervalgoing = true;
setInterval(()=> {
    if (intervalgoing){
        // Do stuff here
    }
})
// Set "intervalgoing" to false to stop it.
```

Answer (score 0):

To continue the countdown, simply call `setInterval` again:

```js
let t = document.querySelector('.time');
let b = document.querySelector('.control');

let state = 'paused';
let count = 0;
let interval = null;
b.addEventListener('click', () => {
  
  if (state === 'paused') {
    
    state = 'running';
    b.textContent = 'Pause';
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      count++;
      t.textContent = `${count}s`;
    }, 1000);
    
  } else {
    
    state = 'paused';
    b.textContent = 'Resume';
    clearInterval(interval);
    
  }
  
});
```

```html
<div class="time">0</div>
<button class="control">Start</button>
```

The above approach does not track partial seconds. For example, clicking pause/resume repetitively, very quickly, will prevent the display from ever showing that a single second has passed. We could get a finer sense of time elapsed by storing a millisecond delta:

```js
let t = document.querySelector('.time');
let b = document.querySelector('.control');

let state = 'paused';
let totalMs = 0;
let playMs = null;
let interval = null;
b.addEventListener('click', () => {
  
  if (state === 'paused') {
    
    state = 'running';
    b.textContent = 'Pause';
    playMs = +new Date(); // int defining start time
    
    let updateFn = () => {
      let ms = totalMs + (new Date() - playMs);
      t.textContent = `${Math.floor(ms * 0.001)}s`;
    };
    interval = setInterval(updateFn, 500);
    updateFn();
    
  } else {
    
    state = 'paused';
    b.textContent = 'Resume';
    totalMs += (new Date() - playMs);
    clearInterval(interval);
    
  }
  
});
```

```html
<div class="time">0s</div>
<button class="control">Start</button>
```